# Remove focus from UIElement in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, textbox, focus, uielement

Do you know, how can I remove focus from `UIElemnent` programatically? The situation is: I need to remove focus from `TextBox`, when I pressed enter. How to handle key pressing I know. Please help me to remove focus from `UIElement` in Silverlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the `Focus` from the `TextBox` after hitting Enter you can call the [Focus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.focus%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method of another Control that you want to focus afterwards.

I think you have no other option than focusing another Control, cause you can´t remove the focus completely.

Comment: Thank you. I hoped for other solution, but I see easy solution can't be done.